# What does out.absolute.dir mean in ant?

Tags: ant

I see in build files of different project in Linux frequently use of `out.absolute.dir` and I'm really curious about what does it exactly mean. I write a short build file which I mentioned in following lines

```
<project name="Test_Ant_APK" default="print">
 <property name="cal.out.dir" location="${out.absolute.dir}"/> 
 <target name="print">
   <echo>p=${cal.out.dir}</echo>
 </target>
</project>
```

And when I run this build file from command line I got this output

```
Buildfile: /home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK/build.xml

print:

    [echo] p=/home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK/${out.absolute.dir}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I little confused about output. I think we should have `p=/home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK` as output. Why do we have `${out.absolute.dir}` at the end of output? what does it mean? Does this build file have problem?

Where does `out.absolute.dir` point exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this started as a comment but became too long so is now an answer)

1. `out.absolute.dir` has no specific meaning in Linux.  It looks like it's a variable used by your Ant build scripts.  If it occurs frequently in many unrelated Ant scripts, it's probably just a common convention used by many Ant users/developers (but still completely arbitrary with no special meaning in itself outside of Ant).
2. `${out.absolute.dir}` is just a way of ensuring that the variable is used unambiguously by the shell if other text immediately follows it - e.g. `${out.absolute.dir}foo` is treated as the variable `$out.absolute.dir` followed by the literal text `foo`, whereas `$out.absolute.dirfoo` is treated as an entirely different variable called `$out.absolute.dirfoo` (which probably doesn't exist and will cause an error in the script or, worse, cause the script to do something it shouldn't, like writing to `/home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK/` rather than to a subdirectory of `.../Test_Ant_APK`)
3. `/home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK/${out.absolute.dir}` just appends the value of the variable `$out.absolute.dir` to `/home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK/`.
4. To find out exactly where that variable points, you'll need to examine the Ant build scripts thoroughly to find the line(s) that assign a value to it.  Without a copy of the scripts, we can't answer that.  I'd suggest running `grep 'out.absolute.dir.*='` on your ant and associated build scripts.  `$out.absolute.dir` may be (and probably is) built up from other variables, so you'll have to look up their values too.

It is possible that the variable is automatically defined by Ant itself.  I don't know Ant anywhere near well enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain it with an example:

Let's say your home directory is `/home/jody`

Lets' say you have a directory under your home called `work`

When you log im, you are automatically in your home directory. Hence when you execute:

```
cd work  #(*)
```

you can find yourself in this `work` directory.

but let's assume you are on some other directory, doing other things and you need to go to this `work` directory. In that case you run

```
cd /home/jody/work   #(**)
```

.

```
(*) is a relative directory
(**) is an absolute directory
```

if you look at the last line before the `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message, you can see the directory path is absolute. I don't know your build process but looks like it is telling you that the path you see is the absolute path as far as I can tell.